# Mysql get position of row after "sum" and "group"

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the position of a single player id in this table in 2 different ways on total_points (2 separate queries is fine unless it can be done in 1?)

For example, If **player_id = 1** -  I need to find out their row position from the total points in two ways:

1. Grouping together and SUM on player_id (includes all season_id and guild_id)
2. Grouping together and SUM on player_id with a specific season_id (includes all guild_id)

.

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| player_id | season_id | guild_id | total_points |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
|         1 |         1 |        1 |            5 |
|         2 |         1 |        2 |            6 |
|         3 |         2 |        1 |            2 |
....
|         1 |         1 |        2 |            4 |
|         2 |         2 |        2 |            4 |
|         4 |         1 |        3 |            8 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

So in this example I would say **player_id = 1** and the result would return to me position 2 since they have the second highest SUM total_points which in this example is 9 (player 2 has 10).

In another query I need to group the results within a season_id. player_id = 1 and season_id = 1 which should return position 1 since they have 9 which is the highest within the season.

I will need to also limit it down by guild_id later but I assume I can figure that out if I get a query that works using player_id and season_id

Any help would be great so I don't have to do all of this inside PHP and iterating over all the database results which is a waste of resources if it can be done in MySQL since this table will eventually have millions of records.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it can be much shorter, but the following query should give what you ask for:

```
SELECT rank
FROM (
    SELECT player_id, total_sum, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank 
    FROM (
        SELECT player_id,  SUM(total_points) AS total_sum
        FROM players
        WHERE season_id=1 -- if you don't want to filter by season, remove this; or add more if you want to filter by other columns
        GROUP BY player_id
        ORDER BY total_sum DESC) AS sq, 
        (SELECT @rank:=0) AS tr
) AS q WHERE player_id = 1;
```

---

#### Explanation of the query

In the deepest subquery you calculate the sum of total points over the data you want:

```
SELECT player_id,  SUM(total_points) AS total_sum
FROM players
WHERE season_id=1 -- if you don't want to filter by season, remove this; or add more if you want to filter by other columns
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY total_sum DESC
```

You can leave out the `WHERE` or add more conditions. The last line shows that you order descending by the sum total, giving the highest first.

Next the previous query is used to calculate the rank using a variable `@rank`:

```
SELECT player_id, total_sum, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank 
FROM (
...) AS sq, 
(SELECT @rank:=0) AS tr
```

which is initialized by:

```
SELECT @rank:=0
```

Finally, over this data you can select what you want to know, for example the rank of `player_id=1`, like shown in the first query.

Comment: The third SELECT "player_id" gives an Unknown column error. The table name is "players" I tried players.player_id but the same error.

Comment: `SELECT rank
FROM (
    SELECT player_id, total_sum, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank 
    FROM (
        SELECT player_id,  SUM(total_points) AS total_sum
        FROM players
        WHERE season_id=1
        GROUP BY player_id
        ORDER BY total_sum DESC) AS sq, 
        (SELECT @rank:=0) AS tr
) AS q WHERE player_id = 1;` == Unknown column 'player_id' in 'field list'  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Start to test whether the subquery is ok, then use that to get the rank (second part of the example), and finally filter from that. I have tested the query on one of my databases, but since you have not put an example online (e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/) I was not able to test it on your database.

Comment: I was being stupid it was correct I had put the wrong table name in was too deep into other code to notice the obvious error. Thank you for your time and help really appreciate it.

Comment: Don't worry, this happens to all of us. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @agold is right.

This is another good solution:

```sql
SELECT 
    player_id, 
    total_sum, 
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY total_sum DESC) as rank
FROM (
    SELECT 
        player_id, 
        SUM(total_points) AS total_sum
    FROM players
    WHERE season_id=1 -- optional filter
    GROUP BY player_id
    ORDER BY total_sum DESC
) AS sq;
```